# Functor error when using a data inside a data: "cannot construct the infinite type"

Tags: haskell, types

While learning more about Haskell's type system, I encountered this toy problem.  When I compile the following code:

```
data SingleData a = SingleData a Int String -- etc.
data DataFail a = DataFail [SingleData a]
instance Functor DataFail where
    fmap f (DataFail xs) = DataFail (map f xs)
```

I get the dreaded "Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b = SingleData b" message on the definition of fmap.  Strangely, the same definition of fmap will work if it is outside of the instance declaration:

```
fmapWorks f (DataFail xs) = DataFail (map f xs)
```

Even stranger, implementing Monoid compiles and works just fine:

```
instance Monoid (DataFail a) where
    mempty = DataFail []
    mappend (DataFail xs) (DataFail ys) = DataFail (xs ++ ys)
```

I believe that this is somehow a result of using SingleData inside of DataFail, because this works just fine as well:

```
data DataSuccess a = DataSuccess [a]
instance Functor DataSuccess where
    fmap f (DataSuccess xs) = DataSuccess (map f xs)
```

Why is Haskell complaining about DataFail's fmap function, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: If you look at the type of `fmapWorks` you'll see that it's not the type needed for `fmap`.

Answer (score 8):

The "Occurs check" error isn't *that* dreaded...

The problem is the function provided to `fmap`.  Try this:

```
instance Functor SingleData where
  fmap f (SingleData a i s) = SingleData (f a) i s

instance Functor DataFail where
  fmap f (DataFail sds) = DataFail $ map (fmap f) sds
```

So, the actual error is your usage of `map`: the type doesn't match.  `Functor` expects it to be of type `a -> b`, but the way you're using it is of type `SingleData a -> SingleData b`; the extra `Functor` instance for `SingleData` allows you to use `fmap` to apply the function directly to the value inside of it.